# How to load Wordpress widget on click

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, widget

OK, got a widget that I want to load in the footer of the main content area, but I don't want it to load on page load.

What I'd ideally like to do is have the widget load in its position with a "click here to load button" (a holder piece of text/code), but then not actually load the widget content until that button is then clicked.

Any simple way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: do you have the code for the widget? or the CSS class of the `<div></div>` it is in?

Comment: Share the site or surrounding code and we can get it sorted for you, it's fairly straight forward though, yes.

Comment: It's actually going to be a shortcode that loads an image gallery, so it would be something along the lines of:

<div class="gallery-container>
[shortcode goes here]
</div>

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing how anything works or a live site, this is all the feedback I can give you. You'll basically need to make an AJAX request to a .php file, you can do this with a get request. The PHP file will need to return the output of the shortcode, so depending on the gallery plugin you're using, they might have  a php specific implementation, otherwise `do_shortcode()` lets you run a shortcode in PHP.

Then you bind the AJAX request to a click event on a button, and render the output to another container, and hide the button.

Be sure to wrap the JS in a document ready function as you see below, because WordPress has a no conflict mode enabled by default, that'll throw your `$` usage off. You'll of course need to include this after including jQuery in your HTML, ideally paste this code at the bottom of your footer.php file, above the closing `</body>` tag.

All this does is toggle the class of "hide" on the gallery section

**HTML**

```
<div class="gallery-container"> 

  <button id="showGallery">Show Gallery</button>

  <div id="galleryShortcode"></div>

</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('shortcodeHere'); ?>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#showGallery').on('click', function() {

    $.get( "shortcode-return.php", function( data ) {
      $( "#galleryShortcode" ).html( data );
    });

   $(this).hide(); //hide the button after data is rendered into element

  });


});
```

Comment: or he can just load it hidden, and then just `show()` or toggle... :-) but that would depend on requirements ... :-) Saves the AJAX though .

Comment: @ObmerkKronen In his original question he said he does not want it to **load** on page load, and tagged the question with AJAX. Hidden elements and associated images are still downloaded if they're in the DOM.

Comment: OK, thank you guys, we'll have a play around with things and see if we can get it working :)